# why is snapToInterval not working for longer arrays in flatlist?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

for some reason the `snapToInterval` isn't snapping properly

code:

```
const ITEM_HEIGHT=60
   <FlatList
    data={Array(150)
      .fill('')
      .map((_, index) => ({ key: index, title: index.toString() }))}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <View style={{ height: ITEM_HEIGHT, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text >{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    )}
    getItemLayout={(data, index) => ({ length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT * index, index })}
    initialScrollIndex={21}
    initialNumToRender={10}
  />
```

and here's how it looks like:
[image]

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem from [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21441)

just add `snapToOffsets` like this:

```
const ITEM_HEIGHT=60

<FlatList
    data={Data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <View
            style={{
                height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold',color:'white' }}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
    )}
    keyExtractor={(_, index) => index.toString()}

    getItemLayout={(_, index) => {
        return { length: ITEM_HEIGHT, offset: ITEM_HEIGHT* index, index };
    }}
    initialScrollIndex={21}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    initialNumToRender={3}
    windowSize={9}
    snapToOffsets={Data.map((x, i) => (i*ITEM_HEIGHT))}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set

> snapToInterval

prop to the height of your item "60".
you don't need getItemLayout if you don't want to use flatlist's snaptoindex or scrollToItem methods. also, I think you forgot to set the value for ITEM_HEIGHT in your getItemLayout prop.

Comment: sorry I forgot to add that to the question, I've fixed it now